# SQL LEARNING/MAX Understanging

Tags: sql, max

I am trying to learn how to use the MAX function in the WHERE CLAUSE.

So say I had a table or 2 tables or 3. And I have

```
col1    col2    col3 
A1      mark    200
A1      Jon     300
A2      Bill    100
A2      Jen     400
A3      will    250
A3      ben     700
```

And I want to return the MAX value for col1 in reference to col 3. SO

```
A1  300
A2  400
A3  700
```

What would be a good idea of how to do this? Should I even be using MAX?

Comment: Use HAVING clause for aggregate function conditions. But here you want GROUP BY, and MAX in the select list.

Comment: What exactly do you want to have in the `WHERE` clause? In your example there is no `WHERE` needed.

Answer (score 2):

The MAX function is an aggregate function which operates on a set of rows.
E.g. if you have

```
select MAX(col3) from table;
```

you get the largest value in col3 of all rows.
In addition you can group the rows with the GROUP BY clause which makes the MAX function to operate only on the rows of each group.
What you're asking for is

```
select col1, MAX(col3) from table GROUP BY col1;
```

This builds groups of rows with an identical value in col1 and for each of those group the maximum of col3 is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

```
SELECT 
    col1, 
    MAX(col3)
FROM 
    table_name
GROUP BY
    col1;
```